# не работает eventEmitter vue js

Tags: vue.js

Учу vue js 3. Решила попробовать в работе eventEmitter.
Есть два компонента Car и Counter, которые выводятся в App. Задача простая, нужно чтобы при клике на кнопку в компоненте Car, менялось состояние переменной в компоненте Counter.
Но этого не происходит, ошибок нет.
Подскажите, что я делаю не так?

**Файл main.js**

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

//eventEmitter
const eventEmitter = require('events');
export default new eventEmitter();

createApp(App).mount('#app');
```

**файл App.vue**

```
<template>
  <div class="App">
     <appCar></appCar>
     <appCounter></appCounter>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Car from './components/Car'
import Counter from './components/Counter'
export default {
  components: {
      appCar: Car,
      appCounter: Counter
  }
}
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

компонент Car.vue

```
<template>
   <div class="Car">
      <button @click="changeCounter">Counter++</button>
   </div>
</template>

<script>
import eventEmitter from '../main'
export default {
   name: "Car",
   methods: {
       changeCounter(){
          eventEmitter.emit('change-counter');
       }
   }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
</style>
```

компонент Counter.vue

```
<template>
   <div class="Counter">
     <h1>Counter: {{ counter }}</h1>
   </div>
</template>

<script>
    import eventEmitter from '../main'
    export default {
        name: "Counter",
        data(){
            return{
                counter: 0
            }
        },
        created() {
            eventEmitter.on('change-counter', function() {
               this.counter++
            });
        }
    }
</script>

<style scoped>
</style>
```

Comment: Хотел было сказать, что нужно использовать стандартную функцию $emit(), но я не знаю Vue 3 ещё. Напишите мне, пожалуйста! Я хотел бы обсудить с Вами задачу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

нужно было обработчик сделать стрелочной функцией, чтобы захватить родительский this:

```
created() {
            eventEmitter.on('change-counter', () => {
               this.counter++
            });
        }
```